How can we use SVG icons with Prime?
We need to use FontAwesome Pro SVG's (and other SVG icons). However, some of the UI elements are constructed in the code, rather than the template. Our developers tell me that it isn't possible to use the SVG's when we build like this and have to therefore rely on the font/css approach to using FontAwesome via class names. I understand we can use the SVG's inline and via template tags.
Here is the setup we're using:
  <p-menu
    #menuElement
    [model]="items"
    [popup]="true"
    appendTo="body"
  >
  </p-menu>

  protected items: MenuItem[] = [
    {
      id: 'ui-session-item-menu-rename',
      label: this.i18nClient.translate(
        'action | session action | rename',
        'Rename',
      ),
      icon: 'fa-solid fa-file-pen',
      command: () => {
        this.editing.set(true)
      },
    },
    {
      id: 'ui-session-item-menu-delete',
      label: this.i18nClient.translate(
        'action | session action | delete',
        'Delete',
      ),
      icon: 'fa-solid fa-trash',
      command: () => {
        this.openDeleteConfirmationModal()
      },
    },
  ]

We've made use of the template tags and inline HTML to construct some of our UI's but would like to be able to leverage more code-orientated design.
Ideally, we would to import the SVG's on a per-component basis and use them in the same way we do the FontAwesome Angular component:
import { faHeart } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    faHeart = faHeart;
}

<fa-icon [icon]="faHeart"></fa-icon>


Convert your SVG to classes and use directly as a class in the configuration object.
.custom-icon {
  width: 25px;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("base64 path");
}

SVG to base 64 encoder
Reference answer

Thanks for the suggestion. I see how this could work, however having to convert the individual SVG's doesn't seem to be an ideal solution. It would be much more preferable to import these icons directly:
import { faHeart, faComment } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@JAK ok all the best!
